# How can I improve performance from my service configuration?

Tags: performance, wcf, silverlight, web-config

I'm in a situation where I have Alot of services that are going to get called frequently in a large silverlight app. After some very light testing we are finding that things are just slowing to a crawly right off. I suspect its from the services becaues its a lot of data from a lot of calls.

I want to reduce the number of calls but short of completely redesigning from the ground up this is currently only going to be partially possible.

All of my services are set to use PerCall in their service behavior and here is my config

```
                <services>
        <service name="MyServices.Service">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeBuffer" contract="MyServices.Interface.Service" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding 
      name="LargeBuffer" 
      closeTimeout="00:10:00" 
      openTimeout="00:10:00" 
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
      sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      >
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Alot of these services don't need a large buffer binding, could that be affecting my performance?

Edit

The calls themselves are running efficiently but as soon as we get to a few hundred requests things come to a crawl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where performance is very important, I have found FastInfoset encoding to be useful. There is a commercial implementation of it by noemax that is very good (not free though it has a free trial).

http://www.noemax.com/products/wcfx/index.html

It also lets you do good compression pretty efficiently.

Disclaimer - I only used it with Windows, not Silverlight. It claims to support silverlight though.